# What ram can i use?

Tags: memory, cpu, dell-inspiron

The intel [website](http://ark.intel.com/products/81015/Intel-Core-i7-4510U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz) tells me that the Intel Core i7-4510U supports DDR3L 1333/1600, LPDDR3 1333/1600. But the [crucial memory](http://eu.crucial.com/eur/en/inspiron-15-%287537%29/CT5092221) site scanned my system and says that i can use 16GB kit (8GBx2) DDR3 PC3-14900, i assume it is 1866 speed? So what should i do? Will it work? I have a dell 7537 laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you can use higher speed RAM, but on the MHZ value the motherboard supports. So you can put 1866 mhz ram into the laptop, but it will work on 1600.
Also, ddr3L <- "L" must be used, the motherboard cannot feed the non "L" (non-Low voltage) RAM modules

Answer (score 0):

The Inspiron 7537 system board supports 1600 MHz DDR3L clock speed memory only.